# opentok No implementation found for native Lcom/opentok/android/BaseAudioDevice

Tags: android, opentok

**When i call "new Session", get a No implementation found error.**

The version of OpenTok Android SDK are: **opentok-android-sdk-2.4.0** running over a Wifi network, using a Galaxy nexus 7 device.

I was using version 2.2 libraries of Opentok for Android, but When updating opentok.jar to 2.4, after adding new handlers required for the build to succeed and to cover all of our old functionality, started having this run time crash

Do you have the LogCat or Screenshots?

03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Lcom/opentok/android/BaseAudioDevice;.initNative:()Z
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.opentok.android.BaseAudioDevice.initNative:()Z
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at com.opentok.android.BaseAudioDevice.initNative(Native Method)
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at com.opentok.android.AudioDeviceManager.initializeDefaultDevice(AudioDeviceManager.java:60)
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at com.opentok.android.Session.(Session.java:430)
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler.appfwk.internal.xmpp.AppFwkCollaborator.connectSession(AppFwkCollaborator.java:815)
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler.agent.MobileAgent.connectCall(MobileAgent.java:666)
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-18 14:14:35.781  12999-13041/net.holisticlabs.digitalbutler W/System.err﹕ at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

What is your code?

```
publishOnConnect = newpublishOnConnect;
sessionid = sessionID;
waitingForConnect = true;
if(sessionObj != null)
{
    Message msg=new Message();
    if(publisherObj != null) {
         View temp = publisherObj.getView();
         List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
         list.add("clear");
         list.add(temp);
         msg.obj = list;
         AppFwkMain.collabviewHandler.sendMessage(msg);
         sessionObj.unpublish(publisherObj);
    }
    sessionObj.disconnect();
    connections = 0;
    publisherObj = null;
    sessionObj = null;
}
try {
    sessionObj = new Session(context,ConfigFile.APIKEY,sessionID);
}
catch ( Exception e)
{
    Log.w(LOGTAG,"session creation fail:", e);
}
sessionObj.setSessionListener(this);
sessionObj.setConnectionListener(this);
sessionObj.setStreamPropertiesListener(this);
sessionObj.connect(Token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update the libopentok.so (native) files. You can find them in the download within the armeabi and x86 directories. Depending on your build tool (ant or gradle) and your IDE (Eclipse or Android Studio) you must place them in the appropriate directories within your project, but you should just be replacing the already existing files. Double check that you've uninstalled the old version of the app on the emulator and/or device, and you've completely cleaned your build directory.